# Show featured entries first without affecting pagination

Tags: entries, pagination

I have an entries field that can be used to select entries to be featured. I know I can remove the featured entries from the loop with this:

```
{% set query = craft.entries.section('blog') %}
{% set featuredIds = entry.featured.ids() %}
{% set query = query.id(['not']|merge(featuredIds)) %}
{% paginate query.limit(5) as pageInfo, entries %}
```

so then I can loop through both the featured entries and then the non-featured ones.

What I can't figure out though, is how to maintain the number of entries on the first page. For example, if there are 3 featured entries, with the way things are now, I'd have 3 + 5 on the first page but then 5 on every page after that.

How do I have it so I'd have 3 featured + 2 non-featured on page 1 and then the rest 5-per-page as normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what I want:

```
{% set featuredIds = entry.featured.ids() %}
{% set notFeaturedIds = query.id(['not']|merge(featuredIds)).ids() %}
{% set allEntries = featuredIds|merge(notFeaturedIds) %}
{% set query = craft.entries.id(allEntries).fixedOrder(true) %}
```